# How can Hamilton's quaternion equation be true?

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

I'm reading Ken Shoemake's explanation of quaternions in David Eberly's book *Game Physics*.  In it, he describes the $\mathbf{i}, \mathbf{j},  \mathbf{k}$ components of quaternions to all equal $\sqrt{-1}$.  Then it states Hamilton's quaternion equation:

$\mathbf{i}^2 = \mathbf{j}^2 = \mathbf{k}^2 = \mathbf{ijk} = \mathbf{-1}$

If $\mathbf{i} = \mathbf{j} = \mathbf{k} = \sqrt{-1}$, then it makes sense how $\mathbf{i}^2 = \mathbf{-1}$.  But $\mathbf{ijk}$ should equal $\mathbf{i}^3$, not $\mathbf{i}^2$.  How does $\mathbf{ijk} = \mathbf{-1}$?

The book's notation says that lowercase bold letters denote a vector, so I'm thinking of $\mathbf{i}$, $\mathbf{j}$, and $\mathbf{k}$ as the basis of the quaternion, similar to the basis of a vector, and can be written $(\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt{-1}, \sqrt{-1})$.  Having the result of $\mathbf{ijk}$ as a bold $\mathbf{-1}$ to me implies that it is the vector $(-1, -1, -1)$.  Is this understanding correct?  In this context, what does it mean to square vector $\mathbf{i}$?  If it equals another vector, then the only operation that makes sense is the cross product, but the cross product of a vector and itself is the zero vector.

Comment: Your first hint about where things were going wrong is that if $i=j=k$, then Hamilton wasted an awful lot of time using three letters instead of one...

Comment: The definition Hamilton gave is algebraic; we can't "solve" for $i$, $j$, and $k$ because he means them as placeholder symbols, more or less. A similar concept is that the [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) which have some use in computation are the reals plus an element which isn't zero, but whose square is $0$. If this doesn't make sense to you, you might do well just to find explicit formulas for how to add & multiply quaternions

Comment: He wrote $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$, nothing more. You can't conclude what you've added. The solution is as you've seen that $ij=k$, $jk=i$ and $ki=j$. Maybe an interresting question is what minimally we would require more of the rules to infer the complete multiplication table for the units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In it, he describes the $\mathbf{i}, \mathbf{j},  \mathbf{k}$ components of quaternions to all equal $\sqrt{-1}$.

Unless he is constructing quaternions from complex numbers, there is no $\sqrt{-1}$ available to be equated with anything.

Instead, these are three independent equations   $i^2 = -1, \quad j^2=-1, \quad k^2=-1$ that are used as part of the definition of a multiplication rule on the 4-dimensional vector space generated by a set of four different vectors that are (arbitrarily) assigned the names $1,i,j,k$.   There are many un-interesting multiplication rules such as $x \ast y = x$ for all vectors $x,y$, but Hamilton found a much more interesting one.

> Then it states Hamilton's quaternion equation:
>
> $\mathbf{i}^2 = \mathbf{j}^2 = \mathbf{k}^2 = \mathbf{ijk} = \mathbf{-1}$

The equation $ijk=-1$ is a mnenomic device for reproducing the full set of defining equations, but is not itself part of the definition.

There are 4x4=16 products of ordered pairs of the generators, and all of them need to be specified in order to define multiplication.  Here only 3 products of pairs are given, and one is supposed to infer the rest from $ijk=-1$ by multiplying that equation on the left or the right by $i,j$ and $k$ in all possible ways, assuming associativity, and applying the previous three rules.

The other rules of quaternion multiplication are $1x = x1 = x$ for all $x$; the $i,j,k$ anticommute when distinct pairs are multiplied (so $ij = -ji$ et cetera); and cyclic permutations of $ij = k$.

This multiplication law is linear in each variable, distributive, associative, noncommutative, and (most unusually) every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse.

> But $\mathbf{ijk}$ should equal $\mathbf{i}^3$, not $\mathbf{i}^2$.
>   How does $\mathbf{ijk} = \mathbf{-1}$?

For example, $ijk = i(jk) = i(i) = -1$.

> The book's notation says that lowercase bold letters denote a vector, so I'm thinking of $\mathbf{i}$, $\mathbf{j}$, and $\mathbf{k}$ as the basis of the quaternion, similar to the basis of a vector,

They are 3 of the 4 basis vectors.  Every quaternion has a unique expression as a**1** + b**i** + c**j** + d**k** for some numbers $a,b,c,d$.

> Having the result of $\mathbf{ijk}$ as a bold $\mathbf{-1}$ to me implies that it is the vector $(-1, -1, -1)$.

It is the vector (-1)**1** where the -1 is a real number and the boldface **1** is one of the basis elements of the quaternions as a vector space.

> In this context, what does it mean to square vector $\mathbf{i}$?

To use Hamilton's multiplication law to multiply that vector by itself.  The result will, by construction, be equal to some other quaternion.  The quaternion that it equals happens to be (-1)**1**, also known as **-1**.

Answer (score 12):

It is **not** true that $i=j=k=\sqrt{-1}$. It is only true that $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$.

Similarly, it is true that $(-2)^2=2^2=4$, but that does not mean that $-2=2=\sqrt 4$.

In fact, the formulas you have written down are *axioms* that form the quaternions. You *decide* that you will look at the division ring (i.e. a ring where you can divide by all numbers but $0$) in which you have $3$ different numbers which all square to $-1$ and which satisfy the equation $ijk=-1$. That's how the quaternions are *defined*. And no, $ijk$ should not be equal to $i^3$, because in fact, $ij=k$, meaning that $ijk=kk=-1$ which fits with your formulas.

Comment: Not a field (because multiplication is not commutative), but an algebra.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks. I believe "division ring" is also allowed? In my language, we have a separate word for "noncommutative field", but I don't know about english...

Comment: Division ring is best, although 'field' has been used for noncommutative fields at certain times by some cultures.

Comment: @5xum: What language is that, and what word would that be, if you don't mind my asking?

Comment: @BrianTung In Slovenian, a ring is "kolobar" (it's a rough translation as there is no direct translation of the word ring. I think "obroč" would be a better one), and a division ring is "obseg" (which, strangely enough, would directly translate into "circumference"). A field is then "polje" ("polje" literally means a field even outside mathematics).

Comment: @5xum: Fascinating!

Comment: The French, it seems, are divided: many use "corps" for field and "corps gauche" for division ring, while others (in particular the followers of Bourbaki) use "corps" for division ring and "corps commutatif" for field.

Answer (score 6):

Because $\mathbf{jk} = \mathbf{i}$, so $\mathbf{ijk} = \mathbf{i}\cdot\mathbf{i} = -1$.  That's the way they're defined; $\mathbf{i}, \mathbf{j}, \mathbf{k}$ are all three separate quantities, each of whose square is equal to $-1$.  Multiplication is associative but not commutative.

We have

$$
\mathbf{ij} = \mathbf{k}, \mathbf{ji} = -\mathbf{k}
$$
$$
\mathbf{jk} = \mathbf{i}, \mathbf{kj} = -\mathbf{i}
$$
$$
\mathbf{ki} = \mathbf{j}, \mathbf{ik} = -\mathbf{j}
$$

These rules can be derived from Hamilton's equation.  Provided that multiplication is performed associatively and carefully, adhering to those rules, one avoids the kind of contradiction you describe.

The $-1$ in Hamilton's equation is generally regarded as the ordinary scalar value $-1$, although one can write quaternions in general as $4$-tuples, with $(a, b, c, d)$ representing $a+b\mathbf{i}+c\mathbf{j}+d\mathbf{k}$.